# Why is the extracted data NoneType? Can it be changed?

Tags: python, csv, int, nonetype

The value returned 'bank_search' is NoneType, but, I need it to be an integer type for a sum later on.

Printing self.accountBalance returns 'None' as the text but it should be a number, I assume the error is in the balanceFinder function, how do you properly search a csv?

```
def __init__(self, details):
    super().__init__(details)
    readFile = csv.reader(open("bank_data.csv", "r"))
    self.lines = list(readFile)
    self.accountBalance = accessAccount.balanceFinder(readFile)

def balanceFinder(readFile):
    for row in readFile:
        if self.accountNumber == row[0]:
            bank_search = row[2]
            return bank_search
```

The result should be 1000, as that is the value in the file being read
The error I get for the sum later on is below:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
Where the NoneType object is self.accountBalance

Comment: You only check for one condition: `if self.accountNumber == row[0]:`. If that criterion isn't met, then the function will return `None`. Maybe add a different return condition for if the account number doesn't contain the first row

Comment: You put the contents of `readFile` into a list, `self.lines`, then instead of using the list in `balanceFinder`, you try and iterate through `readFile` again.

Comment: Note, also, you are working with a list of strings, not a list of integers. But @G.Anderson identified the reason you are getting `None`